# Jest mock material-ui component in order to check their rendering

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I want to test following code with Jest. I am simply trying to mock the `MenuItem` component to see how many times it has been called, but instead I'm receiving an error.

Also I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40600706/testing-jsx-inside-map-function-using-enzyme) question but Material-ui rendered component with weird names.

Then I ended up [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44701030/1239834) but none of pre answered question work for me.

```
{
   menuItems.map(menuItem => (
    <MenuItem key={menuItem.value} value={menuItem.value}>
       {menuItem.description}
    </MenuItem>
   ))
}
```

**test.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import { SimpleSelect } from './SimpleSelect';
import { shallowWithTheme, mountWithTheme } from '../helper';

describe('SimpleSelect component', () => {
  jest.mock('@material-ui/core/MenuItem', () => jest.fn(() => {}));
  let callback;
  beforeEach(() => {
    callback = jest.fn();
  });

  it('should render menu item', () => {
    const menuItems = [
      {
        value: '12',
        description: 'Description 123',
      },
      {
        value: '456',
        description: 'Description 456',
      },
    ];
    mountWithTheme(<SimpleSelect className="test" label="test" selected="default" onChange={callback} menuItems={menuItems} />);
    expect(MenuItem).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

**error**
[image]

**Edited**

```
expect(wrapper.find(MenuItem)).toHaveLength(2); 
expect(wrapper.find(MenuItem).length).toHaveLength(2);
expect(wrapper.find(MenuItem).length).toBe(2);
```

Error

[image]

error with other attempts
[image]

**Edited: 14 Dec, 19**

```
export const shallowWithTheme = children => (
  shallow(children, { theme })
);

export const mountWithTheme = (children, options) => (
  mount(<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>{children}</ThemeProvider>, options)
);
```

**styled-component version 4**

```
"styled-components": "^4.1.1"
```

**wrapper.debug() output**

**with shallowWrapper**

[image]

**with mountWrapper**
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Besides you cannot mock constructor this way you don't need to mock it at all.

Using `shallow()` instead of `mount` + [`find`](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/find.html) you can check count of `MenuItem`. Also check how [`.mockClear()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api.html#mockfnmockclear) works - you don't need to recreate mocked callback.

```
describe('SimpleSelect component', () => {
  let callback = jest.fn();
  beforeEach(() => {
    callback.mockClear();
  });

  it('should render menu item', () => {
    const menuItems = [
      {
        value: '12',
        description: 'Description 123',
      },
      {
        value: '456',
        description: 'Description 456',
      },
    ];
    const wrapper = shallowWithTheme(<SimpleSelect className="test" label="test" selected="default" onChange={callback} menuItems={menuItems} />);
    expect(wrapper.find(MenuItem)).toHaveLength(12);
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks mate, unfortunately that didn't work. I have update the screenshot in my question

Comment: @Carlos, how does your component's export and `shallowWithTheme` exactly look like? I guess you may need `wrapper.dive().find(...)` instead of `wrapper.find(...)` here

Comment: Even with `.dive` it is not working. I am still receiving the object. I have updated my question with `shallowWithTheme`

Comment: for enzyme it's ok for wrapper to be an object. what does [`wrapper.debug()`](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/debug.html) returns?

Comment: how `Table` is related to `SimpleSelect` and `MenuItem`?

Comment: oh, apologise I put wrong screenshot here. updated with correct one